# Icon not found info.plist upon validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

When trying to validate my application I keep getting these errors. These are the Errors:

-Icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: icon.png

-Iphone/Ipod Touch: Info.plist: Unable to verify icon dimesnsions, no icon found. You must define CFBundleIcons, CFBundleIconFiles, CFBundleIconFile, or provide a default Icon.png that is 57x57. I've added the icon to the info section dragged, and dropped. My question is how do I get a Valid Bundle Identifier, and what is it I'm missing thats not letting my "icons" go through?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your icon `Icon.png`, not `icon.png`. Proper CapiTAliSatiOn is important

Comment: Keep getting the return error  CopyPNGFile /Users/maureenschwartz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FVIPNApp-bquleypufzxxgjhbkhwbwetcisdb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FVIPNApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FVIPNApp.app/Icon.png ../../Icon.png
    cd /Users/maureenschwartz/Desktop/FVIPNApp
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Comment: As well as two others "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng" -compress "" /Users/maureenschwartz/Desktop/FVIPNApp/../../Icon.png /Users/maureenschwartz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FVIPNApp-bquleypufzxxgjhbkhwbwetcisdb/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FVIPNApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/FVIPNApp.app/Icon.png

Comment: Not a PNG filCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure

Comment: Sounds like your image isn't a PNG, probably a JPG. Try reading the error messages `Not a PNG`